# Is there a way to program towers of hanoi without recursion/stacks?

Tags: java, loops, recursion, methods, towers-of-hanoi

I recently wrote a program for solving towers of Hanoi using recursion. But is there a way to solve this puzzle without using stacks or recursion- preferably loops or something in that order.

Here's the code I wrote using recursion:

```
static void towerOfHanoi(int n, char from_rod, char to_rod, char aux_rod) 
    { 
        if (n == 1) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Move disk 1 from rod " + from_rod + " to rod " + to_rod); 
            return; 
        } 
        towerOfHanoi(n-1, from_rod, aux_rod, to_rod); 
        System.out.println("Move disk " + n + " from rod " + from_rod + " to rod " + to_rod); 
        towerOfHanoi(n-1, aux_rod, to_rod, from_rod); 
    }
```

Thanks for any help in advance:)

Comment: Hint: you can often replace a recursive implementation with one that uses an explicit loop and a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)).

Comment: Hanoi problem is based on repetitive actions based on slightly varying parameters - frankly, I have no idea of implementation in another way :/

Comment: This is too vague/broad. You should try to solve it on your own, and ask specific questions once you've worked on it. The Wikipedia page on the problem should be a good place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi.

Comment: @MattBall OP asks if it can be done without a recursion and stacks. A solution with a loop and a stack uses stack so the OP wants a different solution. Both using stack and recursion are considered recursive processes so they are indeed the same for the CPU.

Comment: Please try some **research**, e.g. a *web search* for [`towers of hanoi without recursion/stacks`](https://www.google.com/search?q=towers+of+hanoi+without+recursion%2Fstacks) *(from question title)* will provide you with the answers you seek. Question downvoted for lack of research.

Comment: @Andreas It's not very likely to find anything. All solutions to this are essentially recursive processes. I think there might be a mathematical one.

Comment: @Andreas I did try researching, but most of the examples used recursion and or iteration but with stacks implemented.

Comment: @Sylwester Really? Web search leads to Wikipedia page, a reference already given by AMC above, which shows an [iterative solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Iterative_solution), without use of a stack.

Comment: @Andreas That is true, however I wanted to write a solution without stacks or recursion.

Comment: @Dheer Sorry, I pressed enter before proofreading [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708670/is-there-a-way-to-program-towers-of-hanoi-without-recursion-stacks?noredirect=1#comment105569820_59708670). Comment fixed, please read it again.

Comment: @Andreas I stand corrected. That makes O(1) space and O(2^n) time as expected. Usually a lot of the "iterative" solutions of TOH are the recursive one with a loop and a stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It can be programmed without recursion and without stacks (or simulated stacks).

The Wikipedia page on Tower of Hanoi has a section on a [binary solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Binary_solution) where the steps for an N-disk Tower of Hanoi are encoded in the binary representation of the numbers 0 to 2<sup>N</sup>.

I won't copy the full details here, but the core is a neat formula for translating move number `m` to the move to be made:

> Move `m` is from peg `(m & m - 1) % 3` to peg `((m | m - 1) + 1) % 3`,
>   where the disks begin on peg 0 and finish on peg 1 or 2 according as
>   whether the number of disks is even or odd

There is another solution involving Gray codes.